Does AOSP support Wake-on-LAN?
Rationale
I have approximately 15 devices with AOSP distributions installed. These are mostly OEM derivatives, with Google Mobile Services (GMS), installed onto bare metal (via the bootloader's recovery).
I also have some BlissOS installations, operable via WayDroid (installed on Fedora 41, postmarketOS, and openSUSE Tumbleweed, although this shouldn't matter).
Initialising all of these devices can be tiresome. Additionally, sometimes I want to compare hardware capabilities, like boot time. This means that I want them to commence OS initialisation simultaneously.
Consequently, I want to know whether these devices’ and hypervisor(-abstracted)s’ installations can be initialised via a WOL (wake-on-LAN) packet.
Potential Solutions
I've located chromium.googlesource.com/aosp/platform/system/connectivity/shill/+/57a957e8112a42ce0cf16fbe94f6a482b937db42/bin/set_wake_on_lan, but I don't know whether this is what I'm looking for, because I'm no POSIX shell script savant.
reddit.com/r/AndroidTV/comments/zcpqf6/comment/iyycefy appears to indicate that this is included by some Android TV OEMs.

I think the question is asking where there is specific affordance for Wake-on-LAN, like voice assistants in base Android (AOSP).
For this, I believe the answer is no, if you are referring to specific network hardware doing a cold boot of a device from a powered down state. That would require a specific network chip running, and specific circuitry on the main board to start the OS along with the appropriate drivers / Board Support Package (BSP).
For a virtualized Android instance, I would guess that handling the WoL packet is something that the container should be managing.
Based on this post my expectation is that beyond the hardware requirements, modification to the Android Linux kernel would need to be made, which still has references to Wake-On-LAN via ethtool: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android14-qpr3-release:external/kernel-headers/original/uapi/linux/ethtool.h;l=203
It seems ethtool is no longer needed to be ported since Android 10.

Thanks. A shame. I presume that the WOL script that I referenced exists to send WOL packets, rather than receive them, then?

Regarding ethtool, the method by which I get WOL to work on my desktop Linux OSes is by what the Arch Wiki's NetworkManager section describes. Should I have included this in my answer?

Would your answer differ if I had installed BlissOS on the bare metal of my X670E Taichi motherboard? That does have WOL capabilities listed in its EFI GUI, which I have confirmed via an installation of the Fedora 41 KDE Spin. It should also work on Windows 11 Pro (Canary).

If the board has WoL capabilities then its just a matter of the kernel communicating with the UEFI/network chip. I'm looking at the same resources so if you have access to root to update the network chip for WoL via ethtool great, otherwise you would have to create an Android system app/setting for doing such.
